# How to read rtps stream using libvlc (error)

Tags: c++, rtsp, libvlc

I downloaded [this project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplestlibvlcexample) example from sourceForge.
I'm currently trying to modify the "simplest_libvlc_player" project so it can display a rtsp stream of mine...
Here's the `.cpp` code of the project:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "vlc/vlc.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    libvlc_instance_t * inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

 // Load the VLC engine 
    inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);

    m = libvlc_media_new_location(inst, "‪rtsp://user:password@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/stream0/"); //This is the line I changed

 // Create a media player playing environement 
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);

 // No need to keep the media now
    libvlc_media_release (m);

 // play the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_play (mp);

 // Let it play 
    _sleep (5000);

 // Stop playing
    libvlc_media_player_stop (mp);

 // Free the media_player
    libvlc_media_player_release (mp);

    libvlc_release (inst);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

`main input error: open of '?rtsp://user:password@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/stream0' failed`

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong...
My rtsp link works when i open it in VlcMediaPlayer's Open Network Stream...
I don't see anything through wireshark... It's like the program is not even trying to send my credentials to my distant stream...
I also don't know why it puts a '?' before my link in the error.

Comment: `user:password@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is you fuzzing out privacy details and not really in the code, yes?

Comment: of course! hahaha